# Is fairness a part of Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, morality

Is a muslim fair if he:

- [He respects elders and not younger people](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1921)
- [He has mercy on younger people and not elders](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1921)
- He only gives love to the ones he prefer, and not to the people who deserve it
- He only appreciates succesful people, and not the ones who excerted the most effort (like all contests I have ever heard about)

Comment: This particular Muslim you describe first isn't fair secondly doesn't act as a good Muslim. If this is how a person understood the teaching of Islam then this person needs to correct some misunderstandings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if there are any verses in quran or hadith which promotes those points.

Giving respect is a very subjective concept, younger people can disagree with older people if older people are doing something or saying something which is fundamentally wrong to humanity. Disagreeing is considered as not showing respect by most elders, which I feel is wrong. We can respect & still disagree.

Your other two points clearly seems showing partiality. Not sure it's acceptable in islam.

But please share references if you find anything which promotes any of those things in islam.

Comment: I added a hadith for the first point

Comment: @AZeed the hadith you've added first is regarded as weak secondly doesn't support your claim as it shows the contrary. The point is that in the translation only one part of the Arabic term Waqaar وقار was used: respect.